# Python cxfreeze __startup__ not found

Tags: python

I just wrote a small python script asking my printers the level of the toners.

And when i start it from the shell it works!

So I tryed to make a cxfreeze, and then when I run it I get /

```
ImportError: No module named __startup__
```

It is my first script and I really dont know what is that!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from easysnmp import Session

mail = False
imprimantes=""
connect=False

niveauEncre1=100
niveauEncre2=100
niveauEncre3=100
niveauEncre4=100



##Checke le OID niveau encre noir sur la machine
def avoir(addresse):
    tentative=0
    valeur=100
    while tentative < 10 :
        try:
            print(addresse)
    # Create an SNMP session to be used for all our requests
    # print(element)
            session = Session(hostname=addresse, community='public', version=1)

            description = session.get('iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1')
            valeur = int(description.value)
            print(valeur)
            break

        except:
            tentative+=1
            continue
    return valeur

#Teste si la valeur est <20
def blabla(x):
    global mail
    if x < 20:
        mail=True
        return True
    else:
        return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
#Machine 71
    niveauEncre1=avoir('192.168.1.71')
    if blabla(niveauEncre1):
        imprimantes=imprimantes+'192.168.1.71:'+str(niveauEncre1)+'\n'
        print('Imprimante1')

#Machine 72
    niveauEncre2=avoir('192.168.1.72')
    if blabla(niveauEncre2):
        imprimantes=imprimantes+'192.168.1.72:'+str(niveauEncre2)+'\n'
        print('Imprimante2')

#Machine 73
    niveauEncre3=avoir('192.168.1.73')
    if blabla(niveauEncre3):
        imprimantes=imprimantes+'192.168.1.73:'+str(niveauEncre3)+'\n'
        print('Imprimante3')

#Machine 74
    NiveauEncre4=avoir('192.168.1.74')
    if blabla(niveauEncre4):
        imprimantes=imprimantes+'192.168.1.74:'+str(niveauEncre4)+'\n'
        print('Imprimante4')


##Envoi du mail
    print(imprimantes)
    if mail:
        print('envoi du mail')
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = 'stagesofruce@gmail.com'
        msg['To'] = 'stagesofruce@gmail.com'
        msg['Subject'] = 'METS DE LENCRE !!!!!!!' 
        message = imprimantes
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
        mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mailserver.ehlo()
        mailserver.starttls()   
        mailserver.ehlo()
        mailserver.login('stagesofruce@gmail.com', 'password')
        mailserver.sendmail('stagesofruce@gmail.com', 'stagesofruce@gmail.com', msg.as_string())
        mailserver.quit()
        print('mail envoye')
```

Could someone help me find my way?
Thks

Comment: Could you post your setup script for cx-freeze? It will help on solution.

Comment: ofcourse,I just did #cxfreeze snmpfinanalblabla.py  
I've got a new directory called ./dist/
and i go inside and run the executable file called ./snmpblablablaba
then I get this error.
And the setup file is the default one

Comment: Probably your cx-freeze is not importing any dependency on some module you used. Find the module and try `pip show` on this module, get the dependencies and include by yourself.